# Transforming a list via grouping

Tags: scala

Consider the following case classes:

```
case class Objective(goalId: Int, goalName: String, complete: Boolean)

case class Goal(id: Int, name: String, objectives: List[Objective])
```

I have a list of Objectives retrieved from a database. I'd like to transform them into a list of Goals. What is the idiomatic way to do this in Scala?

Basically, I need to:

- Group the Objectives by `goalId` and `goalName`
- Map `goalId` to `id` and `goalName` to `name`
- Set the `objectives` of each Goal to the Objective group

I know how to express that in English, but not Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following code achieves what you are looking for:

```
 > objs.groupBy(o => (o.goalId -> o.goalName)).map{ case ((id,name),os) => Goal(id,name,os) }
```

where `objs` is a `List[Objective]`.

Answer (score 1):

For grouping a `List[Objective]` by `goadId` and `goalName`, try

```
objList.groupBy( o => (o.goalId,o.goalName) )
```

which delivers a map from `Objective` `goalId` and `goalName` onto those instances that match the values of the map's key.

For getting the `Goal` in `List[Goal]` that matches an `o: Objective` try

```
goalList.find(g => g.goalId == o.goalIf && g.name == g.goalName)
```

which delivers an `Option`, namely `Some(goal)` is a match was found, `None` otherwise.